# How to copy a single view with all the data on it in sql server from one database to another database?

Tags: sql-server, database, view, copy

I am looking for some idea if we can generate a script for just one view and run that on the another database to create that view with its datas intact. Please help, thank you

Comment: Are these two databases on the same server or on linked servers?

Comment: These two databases are in two different servers. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your destination server is not linked with the source, getting this data out will take a few more steps. I am assuming that you only want to transport the data from the view, but the steps below could be applied to the source table(s), making this view instantiation part unnecessary.

First, since a view does not store data, it only references data, you will need to instantiate the view into a table.

```
Select *
INTO tblNewTable --this creates a new table from the data selected from the view
FROM dbTest.dbo.Tester;
```

Next, open SSMS. Right click the database, select `tasks`, then `generate scripts`

[image]

Then select the newly created table, and next

[image]

You will need to select `advanced` and change the 'types of data to script' to `schema and data`. It will be `schema only` by default. Select Next and Finish.

[image]

SSMS will export a file, or load a new query window with the code to create a new table, but will also have the insert statements to load the new table exactly as it was on the source server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use following as an example

```
use dbNew;
go

create view dbo.ViewTest as
select * from dbTest.dbo.Tester;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will create table using another table. The new Table will contain all the data of the previous table.

```
Select * into DBName1.SchemaName.NewTableName from DBName2.SchemaName.PreviousTableName
```

You can use this query to create new table in any database and schema.